# Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I have created a Oracle SP with following code. If I execute it from SQL developer then it runs without any error/issue. However, when I try to call the same SP from .NET code, an exception is getting thrown with the message "Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement".

Oracle SP code:

```js
PROCEDURE sp_UpdateLSR(
    po_Info        OUT VARCHAR2,
    pi_gId         IN VARCHAR2,
    pi_cid         IN VARCHAR2
 ) IS pragma autonomous_transaction;
BEGIN

    UPDATE TableName
    SET colName = 6603
    WHERE colName21 = pi_gId AND COL2 = pi_cid;
    COMMIT;
    
    OPEN po_Info FOR SELECT pi_cid as MSG FROM dual;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  ROLLBACK;
   common.sp_InsertErrorLog('sp_Name', SQLCODE, SQLERRM); -- nothing gets logged
 END;
```

my VB.NET code:

```js
Public Function SetValues(ByVal gid As String, ByVal CId As String) As Boolean

     Dim connection As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection(GetConnectionString())
     Dim command As OracleCommand = connection.CreateCommand()
     Dim parameters As OracleParameter = New OracleParameter

     Dim dataAdapter As New OracleDataAdapter(command)
     Dim rtnMsg As String
     Dim ds As New DataSet

            Try
                connection.Open()
                command.Parameters.Add("parameters", OracleDbType.RefCursor, DBNull.Value, ParameterDirection.Output)
                command.Parameters.Add("pi_gId", OracleDbType.Varchar2, gid, ParameterDirection.Input)
                command.Parameters.Add("pi_cid", OracleDbType.Varchar2, CId, ParameterDirection.Input)
                

                command.CommandText = "sp_UpdateLSR"

                dataAdapter.Fill(ds)
                If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    rtnMsg = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0).ToString()
                End If
                SetLIMSValues = rtnMsg.ToLower() = CharId.ToLower()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw New Exception("error", ex)
            Finally
                command.Dispose()
                parameters.Dispose()
                If Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
                    connection.Close()    'close the connection
                End If
            End Try

        End Function
```

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you return a RefCursor for a single static value? Why do you return the input value `pi_cid`? The exception handler is also useless. If the UPDATE fails then it will be rollback anyway. If the errors appear somewhere else then the rollback is useless, because you issued already the COMMIT.

Comment: For a single return value I prefer to use a `FUNCTION` rather than a procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are executing a Stored Procedure against the Database, you need to tell the Command object that, the default is `CommandText`

Add the line:

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

Before or after you set the CommandText - just a convenient place to remember and close by.

Comment: Thank you JayV. [ Not sure how I missed it, I really don't know what to say :) ]